# how to pass variable from php to sed?

Tags: php, sed, raspbian

I'm have a raspbian running on a raspberry pi3, I'm making a system that requires the person to choose the hostname by typing it into a field. And to swap the hostname, I need to change two files inside the /etc/ folder.

I have already managed to make these changes by the sed command, however since I want the person to choose the hostname, I made a form for PHP and wanted to take this variable by POST and pass it on to the sed command.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

<form method="POST">

<input  type="text" name="hostname">
<input type="submit" name="Comentar" value=" Salvar">

</form>

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['Comentar'])){   
        echo "botão foi clicado"."<br/>";
        $SEU_HOSTNAME = $_POST["hostname"];
        echo  "hostname digitado: ".$SEU_HOSTNAME; 


    shell_exec ('

        cd /etc/
        sudo sed -i "s/nome/${SEU_HOSTNAME}/" hosts
        sudo sed -i "s/nome/${SEU_HOSTNAME}/" hostname
    ');

    }

?>
```

Only {} appears in the file that is modified. Would anyone know what I could change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP you need to use double quotes for a string if you want to pass a variables into it.

Additionally if you want to pass user input as a shell script argument, you need to sanitize it, otherwise user will be able to execute any shell script on your machine. In PHP you can use [escapeshellarg](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) for this.

Finally, your code should look like this:

```php
$HOSTNAME=escapeshellarg("s/nome/$SEU_HOSTNAME/");
shell_exec ("
    cd /etc/
    sudo sed -i $HOSTNAME hosts
    sudo sed -i $HOSTNAME hostname
");
```

Comment: Simple and easy. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can only do the variable names in double quotes.

```
shell_exec ('

    cd /etc/
    sudo sed -i "s/nome/'.$SEU_HOSTNAME.'/" hosts
    sudo sed -i "s/nome/'.$SEU_HOSTNAME.'/" hostname
');
```